# What gesture causes the page to zoom in?

Tags: macos, safari

Sometimes, when I am moving the mouse cursor on my Mac Mini, Safari zooms in the page. I checked the mouse settings, and the only gesture that would cause that should be the double-tap, which is not what I am doing.
I have not noticed the same behavior with other browsers, or applications.

[image: screenshot]

What is causing Safari to randomly zoom in the page I am viewing?

Comment: Same question. I like this feature but cannot seem to reproduce it. Apple Geniuses couldn't either. It is some bug that I love but would like to use it on demand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears not the be the case for the Magic Mouse, but with the trackpad, there is a pinch to zoom gesture also. If another finger were touching the trackpad, one finger's movement could be interpreted as a pinch.

[image]

Another option is that some part of your hand is coming in contact with the mouse surface and is being interpreted as a double tap. If you turn off the double tap gesture in System Preferences, does the problem persist?

Comment: Disabling the smart zoom worked. The mouse must be very sensible, even if I cannot enable the smart zoom so easily, when I need.